# How to install other region?

Tags: system-settings

I have only United States for my Region and Formats probably because I have  a custom installed Ubuntu!

[image]
[image]

How do you install another one?

#### update

This is why it doesn't work...how to fix this error?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First reinstall locale package:

```
sudo apt --reinstall install locales
```

Open this file:

```
sudo nano /etc/locale.gen
```

Find this line: `# de_DE.UTF-8 UTF-8`, uncomment it so it's now: `de_DE.UTF-8 UTF-8`. Save the file and run:

```
sudo locale-gen
```

see if you have German now.

Answer (score 1):

If you want German region formats, I think this is a way:

1. Switch to German language, which will generate a few German locales.
2. Switch back to English language.
3. Now you should find some German region options.